# Subdividing and smoothing part of a mesh

Tags: modeling

Does anyone know, is there any way to subdivide and smooth part of geometry in mesh (in example picture necessary polygons(not all i need) are selected) without effecting  other parts and not creating weird shapes.[image]

I append my blender file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MpRbmkZtTWSo28E2p-hI0R3K8L5u8xAx

Comment: I assume you have tried Subdivide, then adjusted the smoothness slider in the floating panel (bottom left of 3D view after you hit Subdivide) ...

Comment: I would say the best is to work the other way around: create an object, smooth it, then sharp the angles you want to be sharp, either with tricks like Crease, Bevel modifier, or with additional edge loops

Comment: When I adjust smoothing in subdivide panel it starts to increase volume of some selected parts. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I will append my .blend file. Maybe you'll fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

@edna's comment is actually the answer, in my opinion. I too have had nightmare creations resulting from using a subsurface or multi-res modifier on the whole model, and creasing, preserving sharp edges etc. It's useful when it's useful, but it adds complexity that you might not need, and it can be hard to fix when overused. Using subdivide on a selection and then adjusting the smoothness and other attributes is better for times when you need higher resolution and smoothness only for certain parts. Example:

[image: Rough axe]

Say I want this to look a little more like and axe. If I multi-res or subsurface modify the whole thing, I will lose all the blocky shapes, and I'll spend a lot of time editing to try and preserve sharpness. In a worst case scenario, I'll end up with lots of extra geometry that interferes with 3d printing, rendering, or whatever. Plus it's just a pain in a simple case like this. So enter subdivide:

[image: settings]

[image: axe puffy]

I turn off "ngons" because if it is on I may create geometrically unsound quads. Make a few cuts, add a bit of smoothness, and now the center of the axe has a puffier shape at the top and bottom. Next, the blade:

[image: blade settings]

[image: blade smooth]

Notice the blade is smooth, but the nearby geometry was allowed to stay simple and pointy. (Real technical terms in use here).

I can proceed like this and make any number of more complex protrusions on an otherwise simple or blocky object. Notice that the parts I left alone remain simple, while other parts have different levels of complexity as required:

[image: axe with several levels of complexity]

I hope that helps.